# Hive: Not in subquery join

Tags: join, hive, subquery

I'm looking for a way to select all values from one table which do no exits in other table. This needs to be done on two variables, not one.

```
select * from tb1 
where tb1.id1 not in (select id1 from tb2) 
and tb1.id2 not in (select id2 from tb2)
```

I cannot use subquery. It needs to be done using joins only.

I tried this:

```
select * from tb1 full join tb2 on
tb1.id1=tb2.id1 and tb1.id2=tb2.id2
```

This works fine with one variable in condition, but not two. 
Please suggest some resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking to get all the data from tb1 with no common data on columns id1 and id2 on tb2, You can use a left outer join on table tb1. Something like

```
SELECT tb1.* FROM tb1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tb2 ON
(tb1.id1=tb2.id1 AND tb1.id2=tb2.id2) 
 WHERE tb2.id1 IS NULL
```